# Сочетание слов в предложении

Tags: грамотная-речь

Можно ли сказать:

*Они предпринимали вмешательства во внутренние дела*?

Comment: Нельзя, конечно. Просто вмешивались.

Comment: По поводу исправления вопроса.  Разве можно так заменить многоточие на вопросительный знак?  Может быть тогда уж так: Можно ли сказать: "Они предпринимали вмешательства во внутренние дела..."?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно, такая фразеология подходит по стилю для внутренних протоколов полицейского расследования и т. п., но в обычной речи или в газетной публикации она звучит неестественно и до жаргонности политизированно. Странно звучит и множественное число от "вмешательства". Видимо, дело в том, что "**вмешательство...**" - это *внешняя оценка* чьих-то действий, в то время как "предпринимать" означает "**приступать к осуществлению чего-либо**" (Ушаков). Трудно себе представить, чтобы кто-то планировал свои действия в абстрактной форме "вмешательства в чьи-то внутренние дела" (*давайте-ка мы вмешаемся в их внутренние дела*), а потом осуществлял в такой форме своё намерение. Поэтому риторически более естественно разграничить чужие действия и их оценку со стороны, например (если приблизиться к исходному тексту):

> Они *предпринимали действия*, расцениваемые (нами, всем мировым
>   сообществом и т. .п) как вмешательство во внутренние дела...